# How to send text into br element using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I am trying to make a tiktok bot, but I am having issues entering in text to their caption section(see screenshot below). I've tried using wait till element clickable function, but for some reason I can not use selenium to detect this element, would anyone have any suggestions on how to go about this, thank you in advance :)

My current code is below:

```
driver.get("https://www.tiktok.com/upload?lang=en")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, waittime).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#root > div > div > div > div > div.jsx-410242825.contents-v2 > div.jsx-2580397738.form-v2 > div.jsx-2580397738.caption-wrap-v2 > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.jsx-1717967343.margin-t-4 > div > div.jsx-1043401508.jsx-723559856.jsx-1657608162.jsx-3887553297.icon-style.hash')))
except:
    driver.quit()
element.click()
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, waittime).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#root > div > div > div > div > div.jsx-410242825.contents-v2 > div.jsx-2580397738.form-v2 > div.jsx-2580397738.caption-wrap-v2 > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.jsx-1717967343.margin-t-4 > div > div.jsx-1043401508.jsx-723559856.jsx-1657608162.jsx-3887553297.editor > div > div > div > div > div > div > span > span > span')))
except:
    driver.quit()
element.clear()
element.send_keys(mainCaption)
```

Element snapshot:

[image: TikTok Caption Code]

Answer (score 1):

### HTML `<br>` Tag

The [`<br>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) tag inserts a single line break. The `<br>` tag is an empty tag which means that it has no end tag and  is useful for writing addresses or poems to enter line breaks, not to add space between paragraphs. Hence, you can't send any text within a `<br>` element.

Presumably, `<br>` tags will have parent/ancestor `<p>` tags. As an example:

```
<p>Be not afraid of greatness.<br>
Some are born great,<br>
some achieve greatness,<br>
and others have greatness thrust upon them.</p>

<p><em>-William Shakespeare</em></p>
```

So in these cases you need to target the parent/ancestor `<p>` tags to send the text.

Comment: That makes sense, the issue is that there is a parent tag, but it only shows up after the br tag is clicked, do you know if selenium lets you click br tags? I will try to see if I can activate the parent tag then select that, but thank you for the help.

Comment: `<br>` tag being an empty, neither you can `click()` nor `send_keys()`

Comment: Dang, Thank you for letting me know, one more thing, if you use click function on a parent tag would that work?

Comment: @TregTownsend That depends on the HTML structure.